# Netbeans 8.2 + wildfly 11 hot deploy not working

Tags: java, maven, jboss, hotdeploy, wildfly-11

I am using Netbeans 8.2 for maven java web application. I am using Wildfly 11.0.0   application server for running the project.

When i change & save the .jsp file, the netbeans deploying and i can see the changes in the web page while refreshing.

But in case of java class, when i change & save the java class file, netbeans showing '**deploying...**' on the status bar. But i can't see the changes in the web  while refreshing.

> In netbeans '**compile on save**' & '**deploy on save**' options are
>   checked.

In standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>


<servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config development="true"/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
```

In a single sentence 'jsp' hot deploying working. java not working

Comment: Your scanner doesn't look to be autodeploying, maybe that's what is missing

Comment: I have also tried with <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="true" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>

Comment: When deploying netbeans should redeploy.

Comment: @srj Did you fix this? I have the same problem

Comment: @ps0604 no. still it remains